# Change method definition

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to change method definition of a class.
That is my case:

(I am importing these classes from another file)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

    def method_a(self):
        print self.str


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.a = A(str)

    def method_b(self):
        self.a.method_a()

#######################################

from module import A, B

def main():
    b = B('hello')

    def my_method_a(self):
        print self.str + 'other definition'

    b.a.method_a = my_method_a
    b.method_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to execute it, I get:

```
my_method_a() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Because it does not get 'self'.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to run `type(b.a.method_a)` before patching the method, you would see `<type 'instancemethod'>`. Running the same code after the patch produces `<type 'function'>`. In order for a function to work properly as a method, it must be an attribute of the *class*, not an instance of the class. The following would work, as you are manually invoking the magic that produces a method from a function:

```
b.a.method_a = my_method_a.__get__(b.a, A)
```

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod for more information.

---

The difference is that when you call `b.a.method_a()` after the patch, `method_a` is an attribute of the *instance* `b.a`, not of the *class* `A`. As a result, the function's `__get__` method is never called to produce an `instancemethod` object which already has `b.a` bound to the first argument of `method_a`.

---

From one perspective, `b.a.method_a()` is identical to `A.method_a(b.a)`. How does Python make that transition? You need to understand the descriptor protocol. All function objects implement the `__get__` method to return an `instancemethod` object, which you can think of as the original function with the first argument bound to the appropriate object. Consider this code:

```
b = B()
b.a.method_a()
```

1. Does `b` have an attribute called `a`? Yes; we set it in `B.__init__`.
2. Does `b.a` have an attribute `method_a`? No.
3. Does `type(b.a)` (that is, `A`) have an attribute `method_a`? Yes.
4. Call `A.method_a.__get__(b.a, A)`, since `method_a` was looked up for an instance. The result is an instance method object, with its first argument bound to `b.a`. (This is why you can consider `b.a.method_a()` identical to `A.method_a(b.a)`).
5. Call the resulting instance method with zero arguments.

Now consider this code.

```
b = B()
b.a.method_a = my_method_a
b.a.method_a()
```

1. Does `b` have an attribute called `a`? Yes; we set it in `B.__init__`.
2. Does `b.a` have an attribute `method_a`? **Yes**. We set it just before we tried to call it.
3. Since `b.a.method_a` was an instance lookup, not a class lookup, the descriptor protocol is not invoked and `b.a.method_a.__get__` is not called, even though `my_method_a` has a `__get__` function just like every other function.
4. Call `b.a.method_a` with zero arguments.

   This produces the error, since the function expects one argument.

Comment: why is this considered acceptable - I would expect proper inheritance and method overrides would be preferable and more understandable and maintainable

Comment: By patching `b.a`, you have already broken inheritance; `b.a` no longer behaves the same as other instances of type `A`.

Comment: i meant doing both classes

Comment: Sorry gkusner, I mistook you for the OP and misinterpreted your question. I'm mostly showing why the naive attempt did not work, and what you would need to do to make it work, via Python's inner workings for how method lookups work. There are some cases where such targeted patching is useful; mocking an object for testing is one case. (The `mock` package, for instance, hides these kinds of details for you.)

Comment: I see what you are saying and agree in principal - but this type of patching just seems wrong from a maintainability standpoint - but it is very cool - I hadn't really ever seen it done.

Comment: Oh, it's absolutely wrong to use in code. :) However, patching it for a unit test makes sense. Suppose `method_a` accessed an external resource such as a database or a web server; you want your tests to be independent of such resources. Suppose `method_a` returns an unpredictable value, such as the current time. You want your tests to be reproducible. In both cases, this kind of patching lets you control what `method_a` returns within the context of a test without cluttering the production code with test hooks.

Comment: Continuing the preceding, patching `method_a` allows you to call `b.method_b()` without having to define a bunch of temporary classes to control the outcome of the call to `method_a` that is buried in the implementation of `method_b`.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use inheritance and method overrides:

```
from module import A, B

class myA(A):
    def method_a(self):
        print self.str + ' other definition'

class myB(B):
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.a = myA(str)

def main():
    b = myB('hello')
    b.method_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```